# Null Pointer Exception Error, not sure why

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception

So I had to create a method that separated input string into first/middle/last names, counted the number of "students" created, etc, and then I had to create a class that tested those methods.

```
public void setName(String newName)
{
    String[] nameInput = newName.split(" ");
    if(nameInput.length == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Error, please enter at least two names.");
        newName = null;
    }
    else if(nameInput.length == 1)
    {
        firstName = nameInput[0];
        middleName = "";
        lastName = nameInput[1];
        newName = firstName +  lastName;
    }
    else if(nameInput.length == 2)
    {
        firstName = nameInput[0];
        middleName = nameInput[1];
        lastName = nameInput[2];
        newName = firstName + middleName + lastName;

    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("Error! You can only enter up to three names.");

    }
}
public String getName()
{
    if (middleName == null)
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
    else
        return firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName;
}

public String getId()
{
    return identifier = generateID();
}

@Override

public String toString()
{
    return getName() + "\n" + "(" + generateID() + ")";
}


private String generateID()
{
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

and this is the way I am testing the code:

```
public static void testStudent()
{
    System.out.println("Trying to create testStudent1 with a single name...");
    testStudent1 = new Student("A");
    System.out.println("testStudent1.toString() is " + testStudent1.toString());
    System.out.println("testStudent1.getFirstName() is " + testStudent1.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("testStudent1.getMiddleName() is " + testStudent1.getMiddleName());
    System.out.println("testStudent1.getLastName() is " + testStudent1.getLastName());

    System.out.println("Trying to create testStudent2 with two names...");
    testStudent1 = new Student("A B");
    System.out.println("testStudent2.toString() is " + testStudent2.toString());
    System.out.println("testStudent2.getFirstName() is " + testStudent2.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("testStudent2.getMiddleName() is " + testStudent2.getMiddleName());
    System.out.println("testStudent2.getLastName() is " + testStudent2.getLastName());

    System.out.println("Trying to create testStudent3 with three names...");
    testStudent1 = new Student("A B C");
    System.out.println("testStudent3.toString() is " + testStudent3.toString());
    System.out.println("testStudent3.getFirstName() is " + testStudent3.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("testStudent3.getMiddleName() is " + testStudent3.getMiddleName());
    System.out.println("testStudent3.getLastName() is " + testStudent3.getLastName());
```

}

I keep running into a null pointer exceptions when it tests toString for a student with 2 names, and I have no clue why.

Comment: This is probably just a class assignment, but ponder this: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: This `while(i < newName.length()) ...` will never stop because `i` is never incremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit*: The issue is with the `testStudent` variable in the `testStudent()` method.

```
System.out.println("Trying to create testStudent1 with a single name...");
testStudent1 = new Student("A");
System.out.println("testStudent1.toString() is " + testStudent1.toString());
System.out.println("testStudent1.getFirstName() is " + testStudent1.getFirstName());
System.out.println("testStudent1.getMiddleName() is " + testStudent1.getMiddleName());
System.out.println("testStudent1.getLastName() is " + testStudent1.getLastName());

System.out.println("Trying to create testStudent2 with two names...");
Student testStudent2 = new Student("A B");
System.out.println("testStudent2.toString() is " + testStudent2.toString());
System.out.println("testStudent2.getFirstName() is " + testStudent2.getFirstName());
System.out.println("testStudent2.getMiddleName() is " + testStudent2.getMiddleName());
System.out.println("testStudent2.getLastName() is " + testStudent2.getLastName());

System.out.println("Trying to create testStudent3 with three names...");
Student testStudent3 = new Student("A B C");
System.out.println("testStudent3.toString() is " + testStudent3.toString());
System.out.println("testStudent3.getFirstName() is " + testStudent3.getFirstName());
System.out.println("testStudent3.getMiddleName() is " + testStudent3.getMiddleName());
System.out.println("testStudent3.getLastName() is " + testStudent3.getLastName());
```

Since you are re-using the `testStudent1` variable to create a new *Object* of `Student` class and not using them to invoke getter functions, it will throw an NPE for `testStudent2` and `testStudent3` variables.

---

*Answer for old issue*: The issue is with your `while` statement. It will never stop.

You can just find out the count by doing `nameInput.length` for the String array.

It should be like this:

```
String[] nameInput = newName.split(" ");
if (nameInput.length == 1)
{
   System.out.println("Error, please enter at least two names.");
   newName = null;
}
else if (nameInput.length == 2)
{ 
  ...
}
else if (nameInput.length == 3)
{ 
  ...
}
else 
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: I  tried the code you sent, but when I input just one name, I get a null pointer exception

Comment: @Anonymous, you can.

Comment: @Anonymous: Get rid of `i` variable. And can you post your code? Im surprised as it will return 1, if you enter one name.

Comment: @Anonymous: Now the problem is with the indexes for the String array `nameInput[1]`. The index should always start with 0. It should be this: `firstName = nameInput[0];` and `middleName = nameInput[1];` and `lastName = nameInput[2];`

Comment: @Anonymous: Please find my code edit. The `if` condition starts with `if (nameInput.length == 1)`

Comment: @Anonymous: Probably its the issue with other method i guess. I can see its running correctly.

Comment: @Anonymous: Run only the part in this function to verify what is the issue.

Comment: I am going to update this question, mind looking over the code? I tried using a debugger, but I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Anonymous: Updating the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Anonymous: Please view my edited answer. The issue is with your `testStudent1` variable in the `testStudent()` method.

Comment: Thank you! I see what I did.

Comment: Glad it was of help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `StringTokenizer` class to help you with this.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer
StringTokenizer test = new StringTokenizer("An example string");
while (test.hasMoreTokens()) {
   System.out.println(test.nextToken());
}
```

Output:

```
An
example
string.
```

The `countTokens()` method can provide how many tokens a string will provide prior processing. That way you will know if you have a middle name or not.

Answer (score 0):

please check trim() method

```
public static void getName(String newName) {
        newName = newName.trim();
        String fullName = null;
        String[] nameInput = newName.split(" ");
        switch (nameInput.length) {
        case 2:
            fullName = mergeName(nameInput[0], "", nameInput[1]);
            break;
        case 3:
            fullName = mergeName(nameInput[0], nameInput[1], nameInput[2]);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Error, please enter at least two names.");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(fullName);
    }

    public static String mergeName(String firstName, String middleName,
            String lastName) {
        String name = firstName+" " + middleName+" " + lastName;
        return name;
    }
```